# Executing Win Forms executable from delphi. Task not working after launch

Tags: c#, delphi, winapi

I am attempting to launch an executable from code written in Codegear Delphi 2007. I have been successful in doing so, but once the executable (which is a winforms app) launched, it does not kick off the `Task` that it is programmed to.

Here is the code I am using to launch the process from Delphi:

```
procedure TfrmMain.OpenDatabase1Click(Sender: TObject);
var filename: string;
var parameters: string;
var
    sei: TShellExecuteInfo;
    ExitCode: DWORD;
begin
  if (OpenDatabaseDialog.Execute)then begin
    //Connect to mysql, check for new data and insert data into sdb file before opening.
    filename := 'C:\mysqlhelper\SSOAP Mysql Helper.exe';
    parameters := '"' + OpenDatabaseDialog.FileName + '"';
    ZeroMemory(@sei, SizeOf(sei));
    sei.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
    sei.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI or SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    sei.lpVerb := PChar('runas');
    sei.lpFile := PChar(filename); // PAnsiChar;
    if parameters <> '' then
      sei.lpParameters := PChar(parameters); // PAnsiChar;
    sei.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL; //Integer;

    if ShellExecuteEx(@sei) then begin
      repeat
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        GetExitCodeProcess(sei.hProcess, ExitCode) ;
      until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) or  Application.Terminated;
    end;

    OpenDatabase(OpenDatabaseDialog.Filename);
  end;
end;
```

Here is the code in C#, that runs just fine as a standalone:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //get command line arguments (should be ssoap database filename
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    //open connections
    OpenMySQLConnection();
    OpenAccessConnection(args[1]);

    //init the lists for FM's and RG's
    flowMeters = new List<FlowMeter>();
    rainGauges = new List<RainGauge>();
    Task t = new Task(new Action(DoWork));
    t.Start();
}
```

I have debugged it to the point that I simply feel the `Task` is not being started. I have placed `MessageBox.Show()` points throughout, and it makes it up to the `t.Start();` part of it.

To clarify, my question is, why on earth can I launch the executable, giving it the parameter it expects, and it just does not launch the `Task`?

Comment: What makes you think the `Task` isn't executing? Show us the `DoWork` method

Comment: Placing a `MessageBox.Show("Blah")` before the call to execute the task works. Placing the same as the first line of the `DoWork()` method does not work. The method is too large to post here, and I believe it to be irrelevant at this point.

Comment: I don't very much like your busy loop in the Delphi program, but that's your problem. Likewise the process handle that you leak. I wonder how you launch the C# application when you run it standalone. I trust you use "Run as administrator" to match the way you launch it from the Delphi program.

Comment: Well I am pretty new to Delphi and that is the only way I have been able to find to wait for execution of another program to complete. I am completely open to suggestion for better practices. And yes, I have run both as admin and both normally. Same result.

Comment: Why are you using `runas` then?

Comment: I am no longer using `runas`... That is how it was written in the example I had found, and so I used it. I did not want to change too much until I figure out why I was having my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious difference between starting the process from the Delphi program, and as a standalone application is the state of the working directory.

1. In the Delphi code, you do not specify a working directory.  And so the new process inherits the working directory of its parent, your Delphi program. You don't say what the working directory of the Delphi program is, so we cannot tell.
2. When starting the C# program outside of the Delphi program, the working directory will be determined by the way that you start the C# program. You don't say how you start the C# program so again we cannot tell what the working directory is.

I suggest that you add some diagnostics code to the C# program to show what the working directory is. If it differs in the two ways to run the program, specify the working directory when you call `ShellExecuteEx`.

If that proves that the working directory is the issue, then you need to work out why the program depends on the working directory. Is that intentional? If so then you need to take care specifying it. More likely, the program should not be dependent on the working directory.

Another possible cause for difference is in the arguments passed to the program. Again use diagnostics output to check that the program really is receiving the same arguments in both modes of starting it.

Finally, I note that you use the `runas` verb from the Delphi code. Perhaps that is the problem. Perhaps you should not be elevating.

---

A couple of asides:

1. Your busy loop in the Delphi program is wasteful. You should wait on the process handle rather than run a busy loop. You may wish to run a separate thread for that to keep the UI alive.
2. You leak the process handle.

Comment: You nailed it man. After just reading a couple lines of your answer, it is the working directory. I was using a relative path in the C# application to point to a text file that I was parsing. `File.ReadAllLines("C:\\mysqlhelper\\mapping.txt");` fixed it temporarily, although they will all reside in the same directory in the end. Ugh, its always something so silly. However, your "asides". I am very new to Delphi. Could you suggest how to rewrite that or maybe provide a link?

Comment: For item 1 you can create a thread and use `WaitForSingleObject` passing the process handle and `INFINITE` for the timeout. Then get the thread to signal the main thread when it is done. Alternatively use `WaitForSingleObject` with a short timeout and call `ProcessMessages`, all in a loop. Ugh! Or use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`. Quite neat but trickier to get right. And uses the dreaded `ProcessMessages`. For the handle leak, you must call `CloseHandle` on it.